# Python Port threading

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x

I'm trying to build a threading port scanner with python3.5, a simple TCP_Full connection port scanner. I'm having a hard time using locks, I've already tried to use Semaphores and the Lock() function in the threading module.

The script works fine, but the output(the closed or opened ports in this case) just comes in a very disordered way, like there were not locks at all. I've tried to use it with locks and without locks and the output comes in a disordered way in both ways. Am I doing something wrong ?

```
import threading,socket
from queue import Queue

host='www.google.co.uk'
print_lock = threading.Lock()

def TCPFull_scan(port):        
    s1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s1.settimeout(0.2)
    try:
        s1.connect((host,port))
        print_lock.acquire()
        print('[>]Port:',port,'is !!Opened!!')        
    except:
       print_lock.acquire()
       print('[!]Port:',port,'is closed')        
    finally:
        print_lock.release()
        s1.close()

que = Queue()

def c_port():
    while True:
        port_c = que.get()
        TCPFull_scan(port_c)
        que.task_done()

for port in range(1,101):
    que.put(port)

for scan in range(1,4):
    t = threading.Thread(target=c_port)
    t.daemon=True
    t.start()

que.join()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not using the lock to print, you should use:

```
s1.connect((host,port))
    with print_lock:
         print("whatever you want to print")
```

instead of

```
s1.connect((host,port))
print_lock.acquire()
print('[>]Port:',port,'is !!Opened!!')
```